# Histogram of P value in practical test?

Tags: r

When I perform a test and observe the histogram of p value, the image is like as follows

[image]

I am quite confused about this. As I know, the p value should serve an uniform distribution, but the picture is not like that. Is there anyone tell me the reason? Thanks a lot! I doubt whether my test is wrong!

Comment: p value follows an uniform distribution only if null hypothesis is true.

Comment: Notice that your first column in the histogram is much taller than your other columns. Your lower p-values are bunched up because `hist` doesn't know how to bin values that span orders-of-magnitude very well. Try transforming your p-values to z-scores or plotting log10(p-value)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am still a little bit confused. In practical test although the null hypothesis is true, it is very hard to get a histogram of p value serving uniform distribution perfectly (like a horizontal line). Is there anyone can give an explain?

Comment: If the null hypothesis is true, the p values are uniformly distributed. Here is an example: `set.seed(42); hist(replicate(1000, t.test(rnorm(1000), rnorm(1000))$p.value))`.